# Why does this result in an error?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, iis

This code always returns a error on submit, any ideas why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Form1').submit(function (event) {
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize()
            }).done(function () {
                // Optionally alert the user of success here...
                alert("Success");
            }).fail(function () {
                // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                alert("Error" + form.serialize());
            });
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        });
    });
```

```
<form id="Form1" action="PostData.aspx?RoomID=1" method="post" runat="server">
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="reportProblem" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;         </button>
     <h4 class="modal-title" id="H3">Report a Problem</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>What are you having a problem with?</p>

          <select class="form-control" id="ProblemSelect" name="ProblemSelect" runat="server">
<option selected="selected" runat="server">Projector</option>
<option runat="server">TV</option>
<option runat="server">Video Conference</option>
<option runat="server">Damage</option>
<option runat="server">Other</option>

</select>



  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <asp:Button type="button" runat="server" Text="Report Problem" class="btn btn-primary"></asp:Button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</form>
```

Found out that this error occurs:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or    cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
```

This is hosted on a Windows Server running IIS7, any ideas?

Comment: It just triggers the fail function every time fail(function () {
                // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                alert("Error" + form.serialize());
            });

Comment: It simply means your ajax request failed. :)

Comment: Run it through firebug?

Comment: Your script on the serverside might return an header with an error status code. Check the data that are returned by your server

Comment: My guess is jquery is not included. _edit - oh k, looked at your error message now._

Comment: @sivatumma JQuery is included

Comment: Edited with the server side error, shall I make a new question?

Comment: If the problem has changed significantly, yes make a new question. If it's the same problem that's been narrowed down, update your original post

Comment: Is the hosting you are using load balanced across multiple servers?

Comment: This is just one server